# create a session to another site

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a backend in Django and I need to log in to another server backend with a simple POST method. So I would need to create a session object or something like that to handle that login.

Any Ideas on how to do that?

Comment: we could answer once you cold show us a peace of code you tried.

Comment: Use any HTTP client library to create a POST request, for example the [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/) module.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really looking for is a [Single Sign On (SSO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).  You might consider [django-openid](http://simonwillison.net/2007/Apr/24/openidconsumer/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for single sign-on, then likely you want to either do the work in the view, and if you need the session to persist, store it in the (local django) session object; or outsource it to something like celery, and again, keep anything you need to keep track of in the session object.